# Why my checkout form accepts Russian characters?

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, special-character

I had an order with the details in Russian characters, so I'd like to block the forms to Alphabetic characters only, I thought that it would be native in Magento 2.

[image: Magento 2 Russian characters in checkout]

How could I an user-friendly method to avoid Russian (Persian, etc) characters in my store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just accept alphanumeric characters, letters from A to Z, numbers space and underscore, you can add an XML file that implements the validation in your checkout.

```
app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

In this file, I added the `alphanumeric` validation to the **company** field.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                                                                            <item name="alphanumeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="fax" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                    <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">...</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you wanna see all the possible validations you can check [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/web/mage/validation.js).

[image: Magento 2 JS validations]

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regex range that covers all the Cyrillic unicode ranges:

```
let pattern = /[\u0400-\u04FF]/;
if (pattern.test("John ПотоцкаяЛ Wick")) console.log("cyrillic; not accpted");
else console.log("not cyrillic; accepted");
```

This validation allows you to block all the Rusian alphabets.

If you only want to accept English alphabets, then use the following Regex:

```
var letterNumber = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Add the required validation to the checkout form.

**Refer these links to do the same**:

1. https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-custom-validation-rule-in-magento-2/
2. https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-validations-before-placing-order-magento-2.html
3. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html

Comment if you need help in adding the validation.

Hope this helps.